# .NET MVC Category Tree URL Structure

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, url, asp.net-mvc-routing, categories

I have some problems with my URL look while going through categories.

Basically, this is some kind of catering application where user selects `Town` (top category), then selects `Restaurant` for that `town`, and inside `restaurant` he can see `food`.

I have `TownViewController`, `RestaurantViewController`, `FoodViewController` and main action that handles representation of `Town`, `Restaurant`, `Food` is `View` (so in every controller).

To see all towns I have `www.catering.com/Town` and thats fine (though it would be better if its /Towns without renaming controller to Towns nor hardcoding new route - if possible)

To see all restaurants for selected town (in this case ID=1) I have `www.catering.com/Restaurant/View/1`. Now here is problem. This should actually be route when restaurant is selected and foods are represented, and for restaurant representation should be `www.catering.com/Town/View/1`. So actually always super category should be in URL.

Because at the end I have `www.catering.com/Food/View/1` and that makes no sense since I'm viewing restaurant not Food with id=1.

Is there some way this can be fixed except classical hardcoding of routes? I managed to work it out with some hardcoded routes but my client said its not good way since it can get pretty messy in bigger projects.

I've done like this:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Restaurant",
        "Town/View/{id}",
        new { controller = "Restaurant", action = "View", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Food",
        "Restaurant/View/{id}",
        new { controller = "Food", action = "View", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest attribute routing. If this is an MVC 5 project, you just need to go into `RouteConfig.cs` and in your `RegisterRoutes` method, uncomment/add the line:

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

Then, you can use the `Route` attribute and `RoutePrefix` attribute to specify the exact URL you want. For example:

```
[RoutePrefix("Town/View/{townId}")]
public class RestaurantController
{
    [Route("")]
    public ActionResult Index(int townId)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

If you aren't running MVC 5, you can add the nuget package, [AttributeRouting](http://attributerouting.net/). The syntax is similar, but slightly different. Instead of using `Route`, you use one a several attributes based on the HTTP method:

```
[RoutePrefix("Town/View/{townId}")]
public class RestaurantController
{
    [GET("")]
    public ActionResult Index(int townId)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks on answer, I'll test that as soon as I get to my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using MVC Areas to further segment your site?  Here is a link explaining the usage: [Walkthrough: Organizing an ASP.NET MVC Application using Areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)